# finite complex with non-finitely generated homology with local coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology, homological-algebra, gr.group-theory

I am looking for an explicit example, if one exists, of a (pointed) finite connected CW-complex $X$ such that some homology group with local coefficients $H_n(X,{\mathbb Z}[\pi_1 X])$ is not a finitely generated ${\mathbb Z}[\pi_1 X]$-module.

Such an example would in particular give a finitely presented group $\pi$, and a chain complex of finitely generated free ${\mathbb Z}[\pi]$-modules whose homology groups are not all finitely generated over ${\mathbb Z}[\pi]$. Suggestions on finding an explicit example of such a chain complex (of length 3, without loss of generality) are also welcome.

Comment: Something very similar was asked and answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100155/second-homotopy-group-of-cayley-complex/100210#100210

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Ricardo points out in the comments, there's an error in my sketched calculation below.  I also didn't notice the requirement that $X$ should be finite, so the natural $BK$ fails on two counts!  However, it seems possible that a presentation complex for $K$ would do the job.  Stallings shows that $\pi_2$ of any complex with $\pi_1=K$ is infinitely generated as a $K$-module.

==========

I think you want to start with a famous example of Stallings, from the paper '[A finitely presented group whose 3-dimensional integral homology is not finitely generated](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=stallings%252C%2520j%2a&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=40&mx-pid=158917)'.  Stallings constructs a finitely presented group $K$ with the property that `there is no projective resolution of $\mathbf{Z}$ over $\mathbf{Z}[K]$ which is finitely generated in dimension 3' (Corollary 1).

In fact, as observed by Bieri, $K$ can be realizes as an explicit subgroup of the direct product of three free groups, $G=F_2\times F_2\times F_2$: $K$ is the kernel of a map $G\to\mathbf{Z}$ that sends every generator to $1$.  So $K$ defines an `explicit' 3-complex, namely a covering space of the natural $K(G,1)$.  As $K$ is 3-dimensional and finitely presented, it follows from Corollary 1 that $H_3(K,\mathbf{Z}[K])$ is infinitely generated.

Stallings's paper was the starting point for many beautiful constructions.  Highlights include the word of [Bieri](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=390078&loc=fromrevtext) and [Bestvina--Brady](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=bestvina&s5=brady&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Nevertheless, and I hope I am not doing something completely silly, doesnt't $H_3(K,{\mathbb Z}[K])=H_3(BK,{\mathbb Z}[K])=H_3(\widetilde{BK},{\mathbb Z})=H_3(pt,{\mathbb Z})=0$ hold?

Comment: It's certainly possible that I've made a mistake---homological algebra isn't my strong point!  But I don't understand your argument, as it doesn't seem to use anything about the group $K$.   Where are you getting $H_3(BK,\mathbb{Z}[K])=H_3(\widetilde{BK},\mathbb{Z})$ from?

Comment: @HW: It is just a property of homology with local coefficients: $H_n(X,{\mathbb Z}[\pi_1 X])=H_n(\tilde{X},{\mathbb Z})$ for any path connected space $X$ with a universal cover $\tilde{X}$. See, for example, the section on local coefficients in Hatcher's book (specifically, example 3H.2 on page 329).

Comment: Ricardo - you're right. When tensoring $C(\widetilde{X})$ with $\mathbb{Z}[K]$, I got $C(X)$ instead of $C(\widetilde{X})$.  Your argument shows that no aspherical space is going to work.  So it turns out that the theory of group homology with local coefficients is rather boring!  I didn't know that.


Comment: @HW: Thanks for your edit. I had not actually looked at Stallings' paper, and so had not noticed his corollary 2. I will restate it here for future convenience: if $X$ is any finite complex with $\pi_1 X=K$ ($K$ is the group Stallings constructs), then $\pi_2 X$ is infinitely generated as a module over ${\mathbb Z}[\pi_1 X] = {\mathbb Z}[K]$. Now we simply note that $\pi_2 X=\pi_2(\tilde{X})=H_2(\tilde{X})=H_2(X,{\mathbb Z}[\pi_1 X])$ using the Hurewicz theorem for $\tilde{X}$. So, as HW points out in his edit, any presentation complex for a finite presentation of $K$ will indeed do the job.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. We got there in the end!